# Preferable way to distribute a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Although Rails and PHP have different deployment methods, what is the preferable way to distribute a FOSS Rails app? Suppose one of the major PHP apps - Magento, Drupal, Wordpress had been build upon RoR, what would have been the preferable way for them to have distributed their application?

Packaging up the code as a gem seems to be the wrong approach for a complete out-of-the-box application, but I could be wrong.

Coming from the world of PHP with its upload-and-go approach, and being a newcomer to Rails, it's rather opaque at the moment to see how code could be easily and effectively distributed.

Comment: You can upload and go with Rails on many hosting providers, however in the Rails community many people take the time to set up the servers on a VPS or other solution. What would be the potential downsides to distributing the source code as a archive?

Comment: @Devin M By archive, do you mean as a gem or a compressed archive?

Comment: As a `.zip` or `.tar.gz`

Comment: @Devin That's what I suspected. I have no problem distributing code as a compressed archive. I just wasn't sure whether it was a common way to distribute an app in the Rails community. Most RoR code seems to either fall into a proprietary app whose source code isn't distributed at all, or gems that are akin to plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packaging a completed Rails app as a gem *is* probably the wrong approach. I think the best solution is to provide access to a git repository or a tarball of your git repo.

If you want to offer your users something more than `rake db:schema:load` to setup your app it's pretty easy to create custom setup commands.

Comment: I like this idea. Can you point me towards some documentation that would help me learn about setting up these custom commands?

Answer (score 1):

Many applications are packaged with the source code just like typical PHP applications. While deploying Rails applications may seem difficult its expected that the user will know how to set up the server properly according to their environment and needs. The only issue you need to worry about is distributing the code, setting up the server is not a domain that you are going to want to help with.

For information on deployment in Rails you should see the deployment page [here](http://rubyonrails.org/deploy).

Answer (score 0):

Well, usually Rails apps run in environment running Apache + Passenger (aka mod_rails).

Deployment is easily done with Capistrano gem.

When you're running Rails app in shared host environment, they usually use fcgi/cgi dispatchers to run Ruby.